# Cant print a value

Tags: python-3.x

I try to get my public ipv4 with the url bellow but when I ask to print it prints none can you guys tell me why ?

code :

```
def GetIp():

    url = "http://www.whatismyip.com?"

    result = requests.get(url)

    result = str(result)

    regex = "^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?<!172\.(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31))(?<!127)(?<!^10)(?<!^0)\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?<!192\.168)(?<!172\.(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31))\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?<!\.255$)$"

    match = re.search(regex,result)

    print(str(match))
```

Comment: Maybe because the `regex` didnt find a match.

Comment: What are you trying to match.?

Comment: a ipv4 string in the page content

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import requests
>>> print requests.get("http://www.whatismyip.com/")
<Response [403]>
```

Looks like the site is refusing your request.  Maybe they don't like scripted requests that don't trigger their adverts.  Here's an alternate approach:

```
>>> print (requests.get("http://ident.me").text)
118.189.157.2
```